# Insert video to sequence editor with python Script

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

i want to create a button for insert a video to video sequence editor.
i have written a script :

```
import bpy, os

class insertVideo(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.invideo"
    bl_label = "Insert Video"

    def execute(self, context):
        episode_path = "F:\\Dokumen\\Target\\Develop Apps\\addon_blender\\tes"
        bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add(episode_path)

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "My Tools"
    bl_idname = "my.panel"
    bl_space_type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Movie File")       
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("scene.invideo", text="Insert Video")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(insertVideo)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(insertVideo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

In **episode_path = "F:\\Dokumen\\Target\\Develop Apps\\addon_blender\\tes"**

I have 3 videos :

1. file1.mov
2. file2.mov
3. file3.mov

I hope, when i click this button :

[image: button]

It will insert all videos from **episode_path**. But, i have a problem. When i click the button, it always show error :

[image]

Maybe you can help me, What did i miss? 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

@cmomoney @sambler Thanks for your answer guys. Finally, i can finish my first addon in blender. I add this in **execute** function :

```
def execute(self, context):
        episode_path = bpy.path.abspath("F:\\Dokumen\\Target\\Develop Apps\\addon_blender\\tes")
        episode_list = os.listdir(episode_path)
        episode_sort = sorted(episode_list)
        first_frame=0
        last_frame=0
        for v in [f for f in episode_sort if f.endswith('.mov')]:
            movs = os.path.join(episode_path,v)
            start_frame = last_frame+first_frame
            bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add(filepath=movs, frame_start=start_frame, channel=1)
            first_frame = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[v].frame_start
            last_frame = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[v].frame_final_duration
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [invoking an operator](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html) in python, there are three positional [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) that are generic to all operators, all other arguments that pass settings specific to the operator **must use** keyword arguments.

So to call the operator you should use -

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add(filepath=video_file)
```

Note that [`movie_strip_add`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.sequencer.html#bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add) will add one video file as a strip, so to add a directory of movies you will want to use a loop.

```
def execute(self, context):
    episode_path = "/path/to/videos/"
    for v in [f for f in os.listdir(episode_path) if f.endswith('.mov')]:
        bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add(filepath=os.path.join(episode_path,v))
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Wow... it's work!!!! Thankyou sambler. You saved me... Hahaha

Comment: Now, i need to set the script. Because, the video always in the frame 0. Thanks for help sambler

Answer (score 5):

You could skip using ops altogether:
[new_movie(name, filepath, channel, frame_start)](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.Sequences.html?highlight=new_movie#bpy.types.Sequences.new_movie)

```
def execute(self, context):
    #create sequence_editor if none exists
    if not bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor:
        bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor_create()
    episode_path = "F:\\Dokumen\\Target\\Develop Apps\\addon_blender\\tes"
    movs = [os.path.join(path,v) for v in os.listdir(episode_path) if v.endswith('.mov')]
    for i in range(len(movs)):
        bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie(os.path.basename(movs[i]), movs[i], i, 1)
```

Doing it this way also gives you more control, like name and what channel and frame for placement.

Comment: Hi cmomoney, i follow your tips but... uhmmm. this script doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe you can explain, why you define variable **v** in **movs** variable. Because, it's always error. error : variable **v** is not define.

Comment: **So, i modified to this :**

for v in [f for f in os.listdir(episode_path) if f.endswith('.mov')]:
    movs = os.path.join(episode_path,v)
    for i in range(len(movs)):
        bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie(os.path.basename(movs[i]), movs[i], i, 1)

Comment: Wow, looks messy.. and, i got this error : sequences.new_movie: unable to open movie file

Comment: v is the variable for the filename found in the episode path that ends with '.mov'. Its joined together with the path and added to the movs list.

Comment: Aaaah.. i see now

Comment: your script is work. I think i made a mistake when run your script yesterday. Sorry.. XD