# How to import multiple files with a gap between them (Video editor)

Tags: python, import, video

I have about *10 000* audio files which contains phrases or voice-lines.

I need to make a single import with the gap (f.e. 60 frames) between them and another gap (f.e. 120 frames) between a array of those files (between categories)

If there is no standard solution to this problem - I know Python just a bit. Then i ask for help in writing the script and for documentation links

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69730/insert-video-to-sequence-editor-with-python-script, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111446/importing-multiple-movie-clips-inside-one-directory-via-script, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/how-to-add-sound-to-sequencer-using-python?noredirect=1, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/how-to-add-sound-to-sequencer-using-python